# Twitter alike htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, twitter, url-rewriting

I want to give users profile urls as **domain.com/their_username**

So I need all alphanumeric character words except few to be rewritten

This is what I have came up with but it **is not working**

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ test.php?f=first&s=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^((admin|def|images|includes|profile|uploads|users)(.*)) test.php?f=second&s=$2$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ index.php?v2=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^search/((.*)/)?(.*)$ index.php?v=search&v2=$2&s=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(faq|privacy|terms|contact|verify)$ index.php?v=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your first rule to the bottom or it will match any alphanumeric characters with the `^(\w+)$` pattern and then stop processing because of the `[L]`ast directive. As currently written one of your other rules will ever match because that pattern will match "admin", "search", or "myusername". The "directory" pattern was changed to a character match of anything that is *not* a forward slash, this usually works better for URL matching than the `.` wildcard as it can be greedy. I typically like to include a `RewriteBase` as well.

```
# Enable mod_rewrite and set the base directory
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# These are directories (directory/SOMETHING)
RewriteRule ^(admin|def|images|includes|profile|uploads|users)/([^/]*) test.php?f=second&s=$2$3 [NC,L]
# Matches p/SOMETHING
RewriteRule ^p/([^/]*)$ index.php?v2=$1 [NC,L]
# Matches search/SOMETHING/QUERY
RewriteRule ^search/(([^/]*)/)?(.*)$ index.php?v=search&v2=$2&s=$3 [NC,L]
# Matches directory (with or without trailing slash)
RewriteRule ^(faq|privacy|terms|contact|verify)/?$ index.php?v=$1 [NC,L]

# No other rules matched, assume this is a username
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ test.php?f=first&s=$1 [NC,L]
```

You can test using http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/